# Accessing a form control from a class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `Get Status` button on my form and the code for that currently looks like this:

```
private void btnGetStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if a runner has been selected
        if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            // Obtain selected runner
            Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;

            // Call the method in Runner class to get the runner's status
            selectedRunner.GetStatus(selectedRunner);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now in the `Runner` class I have:

```
public void GetStatus(Runner selectedRunner)
    {
        if (selectedRunner.HasFinished == true)
        {
            lblRunnerInfo.Text = "Runner has already finished!";
        }
    }
```

What I'm basically trying to do is make the `btnGetStatus` call the `GetStatus` method in the `Runner` class and what I want that method to do is then basically check the boolean `HasFinished` to see if the runner has finished and if they have finished, the `lblRunnerInfo.Text` has a message to reflect this and if the boolean is false, then basically output a message saying "Runner has not yet finished / did not finish"

I'm not quite sure if it's proper practice to access form controls from a class or if it even can be done, but I am not sure of how to do it the way I want (Getting the `GetStatus` method to check the status of the runner rather than getting the `btnGetStatus` to fire the code.)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
lblRunnerInfo.Text = selectedRunner.GetStatus();
```

and then in the runner class:

```
public string GetStatus()
{
    if (this.HasFinished == true)
    {
        return "Runner has already finished!";
    }
    return "Finished";
}
```

Comment: Only thing is I am not sure where to put the `lblRunnerInfo.Text = selectedRunner.GetStatus();` since I tried to put it in the Form Load and it just says `selectedRunner does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @user2929108, you'd want to put that probably inside a timer's `Tick` event because you want it to check periodically. Also, make sure `selectedRunner` is instantiated before starting the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the btnGetStatus_Click as follows:

```
private void btnGetStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if a runner has been selected
    if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // Obtain selected runner
        Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;
        // Call the method in Runner class to get the runner's Status
        // CHANGED
        if (selectedRunner.HasFinished)
            lblRunnerInfo.Text = "Runner has already finished";
    }
}
```

This way, the form handles the output and the Runner class is responsible for "running". If you have a more complex Status Situation later on, then you still can add an enumeration for the states and retrieve the Status instead of just checking for HasFinished. To retrieve the text, you need to add a mapping from the Status enumeration to the appropriate text.

Comment: What about the `GetStatus` method in the Runner class? I'm not entirely sure what code goes in there after making the edits to `btnGetStatus_Click` that you suggest.

Comment: As far as I understand the problem you are trying to solve, it depends on whether you have other significant Status values or not. If not, I'd say the method is redundant; else I'd propose to create an enumeration RunnerStatus that contains all Status values. The GetStatus method Returns the current RunnerStatus of a runner. Printing the text is a presentation issue, so the mapping to the text should not be part of the runner class.

Comment: The reply I made in a comment to Idle_Mind is relevant here

Answer (score 0):

Why not just access your HasFinished() property directly?

```
    private void btnGetStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if a runner has been selected
        if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            // Obtain selected runner
            Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;

            // Call the method in Runner class to get the runner's status
            if (selectedRunner.HasFinished)
            {
                lblRunnerInfo.Text = "Runner has already finished!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblRunnerInfo.Text = "Runner has NOT finished yet!";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do this in a method and call the method in `btnGetStatus_Click`

Comment: Sure...but why?  The Runner() class should only store information and act on itself as a runner.  Making it update the GUI directly breaks the basic rules of OOP.  To update the Label directly you'd have to pass either a reference to the Form or Label itself into the method.

Comment: Was just because it was something I had on my UML diagram; a `ProcessRunner` method for when the runner 'crosses the finish gate' i.e. clicking the `btnProcess` button and `GetStatus` method to display the status of the runner i.e. their time (if they have finished) or display 'DNF - Did Not Finish' if the time is equivalent to 00:00:00

Comment: Well...I would say ProcessRunner() would store the runners finish time and update their status.  GetStatus() could return a string, see neoistheone's answer.  I still think it isn't a good design to modify any UI controls directly from within a class called Runner().

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
private void btnGetStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if a runner has been selected
    if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // Obtain selected runner
        Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;

        // Call the method in Runner class to get the runner's status
        lblRunnerInfo.Text = selectedRunner.GetStatus(selectedRunner);
    }

}
```

then set your GetStatus as string

```
public string GetStatus(Runner selectedRunner)
{
    if (selectedRunner.HasFinished == true)
    {
        return "Runner has already finished!";
    }
}
```